# Is there a minimum weight requirement for flying manned aircraft in controlled airspace (B, C, D, E)?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace

The [Colomban Cri-Cri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colomban_Cri-cri) is a small twin engine plane with an empty weight of ~200 lbs and a MTOW of ~400 lbs.

Can I fly this in controlled airspace? What are the requirements for aircraft registration?

Comment: How do you count lighter-than-air craft? They're allowed into controlled airspace, with a suitable clearance.

Answer (score 1):

If there were any minimum weight requirement for manned aircraft in controlled airspace, the requirement would probably be in 14 CFR Part 91, [Section 126](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.126) through [Section 135](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.135). These are the sections which describe the operating rules for various types of airspace. I looked through those sections, and there are no weight requirements.

I also can't imagine why there *would* be a minimum weight requirement for any class of airspace.

Like most aircraft, the Colomban Cri-Cri must have an airworthiness certificate and a registration certificate ([14 CFR 91.203](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.203)). The regulations describing getting an airworthiness certificate are in [14 CFR 21, Subpart H](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/part-21/subpart-H).

Some aircraft weighing less than about 254 pounds are "Part 103 ultralights" and do not need to be registered. However, this doesn't apply to the Colomban Cri-Cri, because Wikipedia says that it has a cruise speed of 100 knots; Part 103 ultralights must be "not capable of more than 55 knots calibrated airspeed at full power in level flight".

Answer (score 1):

It's not a weight thing, it's an equipment thing. Need a transponder, ADS-B-Out (starting Jan 1 2020) and 2 way radio.  OR, calling ahead and making arrangements if not so equipped.

I don't imagine flying something that light around big jets would be very much fun, altho some of them have smaller runways for smaller GA aircraft.

Boston, for example:
https://img.airnav.com/aptdiag/w240/00409.gif?v=MZPOGC

Comment: Transponder and ADSB would not be required in Class D or E airspace, and 2 way radio not required in Class E.

Comment: Yes,  but the question did not break them out separately.